# Null pointer exception when casting from a service class to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to pop up a dialog from a PhoneListener service class.  I have a DialogBox Activity Class attached.  I am trying to pop the dialog when the call state changes.  I have tried casting from static, apparently I don't understand static at all.  I can never seem to get an activity or context for the AlerDialg.Builder. Here is my call in the PHoneListener class:

```
    DialogBox.onCreateDialog2(1);
```

here is the DialogBox code:

```
    public abstract class DialogBox extends Activity {

static abstract interface DialogBoxPopUp {
    void onCreateDialog(int id);

    void onCreateDialog2(int id);
}

    Dialog dialog = null;
    int DIALOG_X = 1;
    int DIALOG_Y = 2;
    int DIALOG_Z = 3;

    private static Activity activity = null;
    private static final String LOGTAG = "DialogBoxPopUp";

    AlertDialog alertDialog;        

    public   Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch(id) {
        case 1:
            // do the work to define the X Dialog

             AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.getParent());
             PMLog.d(LOGTAG, "Got to PopUp, have an activity?");

                builder
                     .setTitle("Privus Mobile")
                     .setMessage("Lookup this number?")
                     .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                     {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                         {
                             onYes();
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                     {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                         {
                             onNo();
                         }
                     })
                     .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
                     {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
                        {
                            onNo();
                        }
                     })

                     .show();
                PMLog.d(LOGTAG, "Got to show");         

            break;

        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }


    public static void onYes() {

        PrivusPhoneStateListener.lookupCallerId();
    }

    public static void onNo() {

        return;
    }


    public static  Dialog onCreateDialog2(int id) {

             ((DialogBox) activity.getApplicationContext()).onCreateDialog(id);

        return null;
    }
```

}

I get a NullPointerException on 
        ((DialogBox)activity.getApplicationContext()).onCreateDialog(id);

The id passes, but I get a null activity.
Yes, I am not that well acquainted with development code, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: things declared as static do not contain any information about a specific instance of an object. It's not a type of object, therefore you can't "cast" it. If you need access to something from an activity instance in a static method, pass the instance to the method.

Second: your static interface definition is not used in this class, and can be removed. If you want this class to actually implement that interface, you'll need to specify that in the class declaration (public class DialogBox extends Activity implements DialogBoxPopUp).

Third: since your class (DialogBox) extents the Activity object, this is where you'd normally get your context.

Fourth: This class shouldn't be declared as abstract.

Delete the variable "activity" -- your are initializing it to null and never anything else, so it will never have a context.

But here's what I think you want: a class that helps you build a dialog box. If that's the case, you can make the methods static, but you will need to pass a valid context to that static method (I haven't ran or compiled this, so treat it as pseudocode):

```
public class MyDialogBox{
    private MyDialogBox(){} //private constructor so this class can't be instantiated
    public static void ShowDialog(Context c, OnClickListener onYesClick, 
                                     OnClickListener onNoClick, OnCancelListener onCancel){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder
            .setTitle("Privus Mobile")
            .setMessage("Lookup this number?")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, onYesClick)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, onNoClick)
            .setOnCancelListener(onCancel)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Then, in the activity calling the above method:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    //normal implementation code

    public void SomethingHappenedShowMyDialog(){
        MyDialogBox.ShowDialog(
            this, //"this" refers to this activity, and activity extends a context
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MyActivity.this.onYes(); //call the defined method
                }
            },
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //or just define it here
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
                    //do something
                }
            });
    }

    public void onYes(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The activity is initialized as null and is never assigned a value. That's where the NullPointerException comes from.